# weblogic 12cR2 annoying log when using EJB and JAXWS at the same bean

Tags: java, weblogic, jax-ws, weblogic12c, ejb-3.2

I have a Java EE project (MyProject) which contains an EJB project (MyEJB) I created a session bean (Stateless) that is my web service class as well (ServiceAddTEST). The container is weblogic 12.2.1.
Everything goes well but when I call the web service in the console of weblogic below message shown:

```
<Mar 6, 2016 6:30:35 PM IRST> <Error> <Kernel> <BEA-000802> <ExecuteRequest failed
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context pushed was [(pId = 0, pName = DOMAIN, appId = MyProject, appName = MyProject, appVersion = null, mId = /ServiceAddTEST, compName = /ServiceAddTEST)], but context being popped is [(pId = 0, pName = DOMAIN, appId = MyProject, appName = MyProject, appVersion = null, mId = MyEJB, compName = ServiceAddTEST)].
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context pushed was [(pId = 0, pName = DOMAIN, appId = MyProject, appName = MyProject, appVersion = null, mId = /ServiceAddTEST, compName = /ServiceAddTEST)], but context being popped is [(pId = 0, pName = DOMAIN, appId = MyProject, appName = MyProject, appVersion = null, mId = MyEJB, compName = ServiceAddTEST)]
        at weblogic.application.ComponentInvocationContextManagerImpl$4.validate(ComponentInvocationContextManagerImpl.java:256)
        at weblogic.application.ComponentInvocationContextManagerImpl$4.close(ComponentInvocationContextManagerImpl.java:231)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

However, the web service works fine. I want to solve the problem to get rid of this log, i think it can cause some problems later.
Additionally, there is no any extra information in the log file. Below is the code of the class:

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class ServiceAddTEST {


    @WebMethod
    public int getCount(){
        return 20;
    }
```

About environment:

- Eclipse Mars
- Java 1.8.0_71
- Weblogic 12.2.1
- EJB 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue will be fixed in Version release 12.2.2.1.0 as [claimed here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3881162?start=0&tstart=0)

**Edit**

Fixed by application of the [patch **22648025**](https://support.oracle.com:443/epmos/faces/PatchSearchResults?searchdata=%3Ccontext%20type%3D%22BASIC%22%20search%3D%22%26lt%3BSearch%26gt%3B%0A%26lt%3BFilter%20name%3D%26quot%3Bpatch_number%26quot%3B%20op%3D%26quot%3Bis%26quot%3B%20value%3D%26quot%3B22648025%26quot%3B%2F%26gt%3B%0A%26lt%3BFilter%20name%3D%26quot%3Bexclude_superseded%26quot%3B%20op%3D%26quot%3Bis%26quot%3B%20value%3D%26quot%3Bfalse%26quot%3B%2F%26gt%3B%0A%26lt%3B%2FSearch%26gt%3B%22%2F%3E) (you need an Oracle support account to get it)

Comment: Thank you. This problem is too silly. I think most of developers who use Weblogic want to have EJB and Web Services in a same class. It seems that Oracle Developers did not test it even once!

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the problem a lot, finally i found that It could be a bug of weblogic12cR2, because the scenario is really simple. See this [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3881162?start=0&tstart=07Z7VGsJU-SMF3Kg).
I decided to downgrade weblogic, now I am using Weblogic 12.1.2 and it works fine.